# Postgres full-text search: make a tsvector by splitting on whitespace or by providing an array of tokens

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a text search problem where I need to search systematically-generated text, i.e. *not* human-written natural language text.

The typical `ts_tovector('english', 'foo bar baz')` is not particularly helpful. In some cases it generates tokens which I know will be lead to false-positive search results.

Instead I'd really just like to either provide the tokens in a string where each token is separated by whitespace, or provide an array of ordered tokens.

For example, something along the lines of `to_tsvector(array["foo", "bar", "baz"])` should produce three tokens: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. This seems like a pretty basic thing, but so far I haven't found any explicit documentation of this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a basic thing, and all you have to do is use the `simple` text search configuration:

```
to_tsvector('simple', 'foo bar baz')
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found `array_to_tsvector` works nicely for taking an array of pre-computed tokens.

Comment: Ah, good. I have removed the misleading part of my answer.